# Docusign Certified Deliveries - why is there a total tab count?

Tags: docusignapi

This is with the REST API. I didn't think any tabs would apply to a recipient who was classified as a certified delivery. Any info on this?

Comment: Can you please share the API you are using and the request and response.

Comment: I used the ListRecipients call to get a Recipients instance, then I was looping over the CertifiedDelivery list contained in the Recipients. I was just confused about why there would be a total tab count when the certified delivery can't have any type of tabs, as far as I know.

Comment: I am interested in seeing your Json request for create Envelope. As far as I am seeing the totalTabCount property for certifiedDeliveries list is being returned as Zero

Comment: My only comment was that if it's always zero, then why have that data member. I thought I might be missing something. I was hoping that someone had a test case where it would be populated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More likely than not, "under the covers" (i.e., in the API design itself), all recipient types are defined such that they share the same list of "base" properties.  If you're seeing the **totalTabCount** property for a Certified Delivery recipient, I'd imagine this is simply because that property is one of the "base" properties that is defined for every type of recipient.  That said though, the value of that property for a Certified Delivery recipient should always be zero (since, as you point out, CD recipients shouldn't have any tabs).

Comment: Sounds like a likely explanation. Thank you.